# Is it possible to hook into firestore retrieval/storing functions for automatic serialization/deserialization?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore doesn't support storing all types of objects you might use in an app. One such type is a nested array. So when storing such an object, you needs to convert it (for example with JSON.stringify) and the opposite goes for when you retrieve the object from firestore. While this works, you have to do the conversion in every place you retrieve/store the object.

**Question:** Is it possible to hook into the firestore retrieval/storing from/to a collection so you only need to supply a conversion function once?

Currently using firestore Web version 9 with a React frontend.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The Firebase SDK supports a user defining a converter with type `FirestoreDataConverter` to be supplied in a collection reference's `withConverter` method. The converter will define both a `toFirestore` method and a `fromFirestore` method.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter

> Converter used by `withConverter()` to transform user objects of type T into Firestore data.
>
> Using the converter allows you to specify generic type arguments when storing and retrieving objects from Firestore.

**Example**

```ts
class Post {
  constructor(readonly title: string, readonly author: string) {}

  toString(): string {
    return this.title + ', by ' + this.author;
  }
}

const postConverter = {
  toFirestore(post: Post): firebase.firestore.DocumentData {
    return {title: post.title, author: post.author};
  },
  fromFirestore(
    snapshot: firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot,
    options: firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions
  ): Post {
    const data = snapshot.data(options)!;
    return new Post(data.title, data.author);
  }
};

const postSnap = await firebase.firestore()
  .collection('posts')
  .withConverter(postConverter)
  .doc().get();
const post = postSnap.data();
if (post !== undefined) {
  post.title; // string
  post.toString(); // Should be defined
  post.someNonExistentProperty; // TS error
}
```